# javax/xml/bind/JAXBException building with gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm trying to update to gradle 5.4 and thus JDK 11 but I'm having errors when building:

```
 Task :app:compileDesarrolloDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDesarrolloDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
```

I've been searching for some solution and I found that I had to add some dependencies on my app/build.gradle because Java 9+ does not install jre anymore:

```
compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.0'
compile group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-core', version: '2.3.0'
compile group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: '2.3.0'
compile group: 'javax.activation', name: 'activation', version: '1.1.1'
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime', version: '2.3.1'
```

But I'm still getting the same error:

```
javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException

org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException
: 
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDesarrolloDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Open stacktrace
Caused by: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
: 
javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
Open stacktrace
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
: 
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
Close stacktrace
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.instantiateProcessor(AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.java:149)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.setupProcessors(AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.java:108)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.call(AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.java:91)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ResourceCleaningCompilationTask.call(ResourceCleaningCompilationTask.java:57)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:50)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:38)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:37)
...
```

Full app/build.gradle: https://gist.github.com/vivoconunxino/a68d2011bc1b184a83786a6268533087

Full error: https://gist.github.com/vivoconunxino/1a27586133b34adbbe8314395e6704a1

Comment: Please let me know if any more relevant info is needed, I'll gladly edit the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I'm just trying to make a comment, but do not have enough reputation to make one.

I just ran into this issue today, when attempting to build an Android App with Gradle 6.1.1 (also tried on 5.4.1), and using JDK 11, on macOS 10.15.3 (Catalina).

I fixed this issue by downgrading my JDK, to JDK8, since according to this ([How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j)), apparently JAXB was removed in JDK 11.

I feel like this is an issue related to a Gradle plugin (possibly com.android.application, or a kotlin plugin), since I built JNI via Gradle with JDK11.

Comment: It's not the answer I expected, but in the end I could not fix it in any other way than that. I also had to downgrade the JDK. Weird, it should be possible adding some dependency. For the moment this is the only answer, hope points serve you for commenting next time!

Answer (score 11):

I found this issue as well.

I added the following to my gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    [...]
    implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.3'

    annotationProcessor 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3'
    annotationProcessor 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.3'
    annotationProcessor 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
}
```

Comment: Finally the answer which helped me solve the problem. However, I had to remove implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3' to avoid error: D8: Program type already present: javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException, and add:
```
android {
...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.md'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.md'
    }
}
``` to avoid: "More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/LICENSE.md'"

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me solve my problem.

Comment: Could you pls show us the way you find the solution?

Comment: @lrnrzg  I don't remember the details, I may have google'd 
   "com.sun.xml.bind replacement" and found the answer.